# OpenGL ES 2.0 Inner face color on iPad

Tags: ipad, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I have an application that loads and displays obj files in 3D(I use ninevehGL for it), and I would like to know if it is possible to color the inner faces of an object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable culling via `glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE)` and set a different color on fragments where `gl_FrontFace` is `false`.